# using distinct with groupby and where clause in influx

Tags: sql, database, influxdb

I have a table in influx in which I am storing minute by minute values of hosts for different domains. some domains have multiple hosts and some have just one.

every host is having some values which I am getting by doing a group by every minute with the below query:-

```
q = 'SELECT sum(\"value\") FROM \"mph.oper.users\" WHERE \"host\" =~ /mphhos-{0}| *mph-{0}/ AND time > now() - {1}d and time < now() - 1m GROUP BY time(1m) fill(none);'.format(
        domain, duration)
```

I want to check if within the same minute if I am having multiple data point from the same host and I want to do the sum on unique hosts.

Answer (score 0):

I want to say something to do with HAVING but could you expand your question?

```
q =  
'SELECT sum(\"value\")
 FROM \"mph.oper.users\" 
 WHERE 
  \"host\" =~ /mphhos-{0}| *mph-{0}/ 
  AND time > now() - {1}d 
  AND time < now() - 1m 
 GROUP BY time(1m) fill(none);'.format(domain, duration)
```

Comment: you copy and pasted my query.....What do you wanna say?

Comment: the host should be disntict